# ¿Cómo actualizar el valor de un input?

Tags: php, html

Hola a través de un formulario estoy modificando los datos de unos inputs, todo funciona correctamente pero cuando mando el formulario en los inputs siguen saliendo los valores anteriores y no se actualizan hasta que vuelvo a cargar la página. No puedo hacer que la página se recargue porque no puedo usar la función header(). Gracias.

Como muestro el valor del input:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" required value="<?php echo ($emparray[0]['nombre1']) ?>">
```

Código php:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
```

Inicio las variables para conectarme a la base de datos y ejecuto la query.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result) {

            while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                $emparray[] = $row;
            //echo(json_encode($emparray));           
        }else{
            echo(mysqli_error($connection));       
        }
```

Lleno el vector y ejecuto una query para hacer el update en la base de datos. Vuelvo a cargar los datos actualizados y los meto en el mismo array sustituyendo los datos anteriores.

Para recoger los datos de los inputs en el envío del post:

```
        $names[$i] = $_POST["name".$i];
        $emails[$i] = $_POST["email".$i];
        $telefons[$i] = $_POST["telefon".$i];
        $dnis[$i] = $_POST["dni".$i];
```

Comment: Sería recomendable que enseñaras parte del código para tener algo por donde empezar.

Comment: Debes saber que los elementos de formularios se recuperan: 1. Mediante los métodos `POST`, `GET`, o `REQUEST`. 2. Que para obtenerlos se debe usar el atributo `name` que se ha dado al elemento en el formulario. Por ejemplo, para recuperar el valor de tu input, una vez éste haya sido enviado, deberías hacerlo con `$POST["name1"]`. Creo que deberías revisar esos conceptos básicos en el Manual de PHP.

Comment: Creo que no me explico muy bien, perdón. Yo consigo obtener todos los datos que se introducen en los inputs y consigo actualizarlos en la base de datos, también los consigo obtener y introducir en los imputs perfectamente. El problema es que al actualizar los datos de los inputs cuando yo envío el formulario no salen actualizados hasta que no vuelvo a cargar la página.

Comment: Al enviar el formulario se recarga la página, no estoy utilizando nada de código javascript.

Comment: Entonces, aparentemente estás leyendo de la base de datos los valores anteriores antes de grabar los que estás recibiendo por POST... ¿Podrías mostrar el código de toda la página (o al menos estas partes relevantes) para hacernos una idea de qué pasos estás realizando en el orden inverso?

Comment: Actualizo en post

Comment: Ok, veo que estás asignando los valores bien, pero creo que es necesario ver todo el código junto (toda la página, o al menos la parte que publicaste de corrido) para entender el orden en el que estás haciendo cada cosa.

Comment: Pero aquí: `<?php echo ($emparray[0]['nombre1']) ?>` ¿a qué corresponde `nombre1` exactamente?

Comment: Como podéis ver yo igualo el vector $emparray[] a $row guardando así los datos que devuelve la query, nombre1 es un campo de la base de datos, porque así está indexado el vector. Te podría poner más código pero realmente utilizo el mismo código el if($result) { con while todo el rato lo único que cambia es la query que yo ejecuto, update insert select etc..

Comment: Pero escribes el HTML del formulario antes o después de la consulta?

Comment: Lo primero que hay en el código es el script en php así que lo primero que se ejecuta es la consulta y luego se crea todo el formulario con los campos del vector.

Comment: Yo sigo sin entender nada. ¿Puedes por favor explicar en la pregunta **el orden** en el que haces las cosas?. Si lo haces en el orden en el que están ahora no le veo ningún sentido, a no ser que uses Ajax, que por lo demás sería lo mejor, para no tener que recargar la página. Pero si recargas la página luego de la petición que haces a la base de datos, lo que haces en el input, o sea, lo primero que pones en la pregunta, deberías hacerlo después... enviando un post con el array resultado de la base de datos, el cual recuperarías y leerías al recargar la página.

Comment: El problema es que tu cargas las variables por medio de php y solo se ejecuta una vez cada que cargas la pagina, una pregunta al hacer el submit ser recarga tu pagina? lo envias a la  misma pagina en el Action para que se recarguen los datos? Saludos...